# Finding and Listing Duplicate Words in a Plain Text file

Tags: linux

I have a rather large file that I am trying to make sense of.
I generated a list of my entire directory structure that contains a lot of files using the du -ah command.
The result basically lists all the folders under a specific folder and the consequent files inside the folder in plain text format.

eg:

```
4.0G    ./REEL_02/SCANS/200113/001/Promise Pegasus/BMB 10/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/18-09-12/CAM B/B119_0918NO/B119_0918NO.RDM/B119_C004_0918XJ.RDC/B119_C004_0918XJ_003.R3D
3.1G    ./REEL_02/SCANS/200113/001/Promise Pegasus/BMB 10/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/18-09-12/CAM B/B119_0918NO/B119_0918NO.RDM/B119_C004_0918XJ.RDC/B119_C004_0918XJ_004.R3D
15G ./REEL_02/SCANS/200113/001/Promise Pegasus/BMB 10/RED EPIC DATA/R3D/18-09-12/CAM B/B119_0918NO/B119_0918NO.RDM/B119_C004_0918XJ.RDC
```

Is there any command that I can run or utility that I can use that will help me identify if there is more than one record of the same filename **(usually the last 16 characters in each line + extension)** and if such duplicate entries exist, to write out the entire path (full line) to a different text file so i can find and move out duplicate files from my NAS, using a script or something.

Please let me know as this is incredibly stressful to do when the plaintext file itself is 5.2Mb :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split each line on `/`, get the last item (`cut` cannot do it, so revert each line and take the first one), then sort and run `uniq` with `-d` which shows duplicates.

```
rev FILE | cut -f1 -d/ | rev | sort | uniq -d
```

Comment: Hi there
Thanks so much for this.
This seems to do the task exactly as expected and it serves my purpose of listing out all the duplicates.
Unfortunately, I am having to search for the path individually with this method.

Is there anyway to append the file with the full path name as well so i can manually go there and delete/move the file to another deep archive location?
Is there a way to move all these duplicates its found to a different folder maybe?

Maybe do a search in the directory itself and move or copy all duplicate files to a new folder. That'd help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve here, but I have the feeling that you are doing it in a difficult way anyway :) Your text file seems to contain spaces in files which make it hard to parse.

I take it that you want to find all files whose name is duplicate. I would start with something like:

```
 find DIR -type f -printf '%f\n' | uniq -d
```

That means

- DIR - look for files in this directory
- '-type f' - print only files (not directories or other special files)
- -printf '%f' - do not use default find output format, print only file name of each file
- uniq -d - print only lines which occur multiple times

You may want to list only some files, not all of them. You can limit which files are taken into account by more rules to find. If you care only about *.R3D and *.RDC files you can use

```
find . \( -name '*.RDC' -o -name '*.R3D' \) -type f -printf '%f\n' | ...
```

If I wrongly guessed what you need, sorry :)

Comment: Hi there
Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, I am not getting any verbose responses when typing this command out. Although an iteration of the command posted above, i cant get this to work after several attempts.

Answer (score 0):

The following will scan the current subdirectory (using [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)) and print the full path to duplicate files. You can adapt it take a different action, e.g. delete/move the duplicate files.

```bash
while IFS="|" read FNAME LINE; do
    # FNAME contains the filename (without dir), LINE contains the full path
    if [ "$PREV" != "$FNAME" ]; then
        PREV="$FNAME"  # new filename found. store
    else
        echo "Duplicate : $LINE"  # duplicate filename. Do something with it
    fi
done < <(find . -type f -printf "%f|%p\n" | sort -s)
```

To try it out, simply copy paste that into a bash shell or save it as a script.

Note that:

- due to the `sort`, the list of files will have to be loaded into memory before the loop begins so the performance will be affected by the number of files returned
- the order the files appears after a `sort` will affect which files are treated as duplicates since the first occurence is assumed to be the *original*. The `-s` options ensures a stable sort, which means the order will be dictated by `find`.

---

A more straight-forward by less robust robust approach would be something along the lines of:

```
find . -type f -printf "%20f %p\n" | sort | uniq -D -w20 | cut -c 22-
```

That will print all files that have duplicate entries, assuming that the longest filename will be 30 characters long. The output differs from the solution above in all entries with the same name are listed (not `N-1` entries as above).

You'll need to change the numbers in the `find`, `uniq` and `cut` commands to match the actual case. A number too small may result in false positives.

```
find . -type f -printf "%20f %p\n" | sort | uniq -D -w20 | cut -c 22-
----------------------------------   ----   ------------   ----------
                |                      |          |               |
   Find all files in current dir       |          |               |
   and subdirs and print out           |    print out all         | 
   the filename (padded to 20          |    entries that          | 
   characters) followed by the         |    have duplicates       | 
   full path                           |    but only look at      |  
                                       |    the first 20 chars    |
                                       |                          |
                                 Sort the output          Discard the first
                                                          21 chars of each line
```

Comment: Hi Shawn
Thanks so much for replying.

Unfortunately, this NAS is a closed group NAS and I am not allowed to run python on this box. The vendor we procured it from has strict rules to not run any application/scripting languages on this box so I am restricted in my access to other applications.

All i am trying to do is find duplicates files in a directory with the same name and to move them to a new folder, maintaining the subfolder architecture of the file.

Any linux commands u can think of that will help me sort this out?

Comment: Hey Shawn, let me give this a crack. But my entire folder is quite large (28Tb) to be precise.

My logic was the write out to text file and then sort, find duplicates, then write out only duplicates to a separate text file and then use that file to move shots to a different folder.

Once i am done with my testing, I'll get back.

Comment: The solution above can be broken down in to separate steps if required, i.e. running the `find` command and redirecting the to a file. You can then perform the sort+uniq commands on the file and write its output to another file to contain only the duplicate files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for fslint: http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/

It can find duplicate files, broken links, and stuff like that.

Comment: Hey there LTWorf
Unfortunately, the vendor of my NAS box will not allow any third party installations on the box itself. So the aforementioned option was tried, but i am looking at doing this through Linux command line alone cause its a Linux NAS.