# How do I find and print duplicate words in a document with the linux Find command?

Tags: linux, text, find, code-duplication

I want to find out if variable names are duplicated.
So,
I want to find duplicate words.
In addition,
  Is it possible to output duplicate word lines?
I found it on the internet but it does not work.

```
 # grep test.php | awk ‘{print $3}’ | sort | uniq -dc
```

example.

```
$color2=$_POST['color2'] ?? '';
$color1=$_POST['color1'] ?? '';
$color3=$_POST['color3'] ?? '';
$color5=$_POST['color5'] ?? '';

$color6=$_POST['color6'] ?? '';
$color3=$_POST['color3'] ?? '';
$color8=$_POST['color8'] ?? '';
$color9=$_POST['color9'] ?? '';

$color13=$_POST['color13'] ?? '';
$color10=$_POST['color10'] ?? '';
$color11=$_POST['color11'] ?? '';
$color12=$_POST['color12'] ?? '';

$color13=$_POST['color13'] ?? '';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding and Listing Duplicate Words in a Plain Text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645262/finding-and-listing-duplicate-words-in-a-plain-text-file)

Comment: Any time you have that much code duplication, it's a code smell. This should have been two variables, not two dozen. Finding duplicates is a XY problem, you should refactor your code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create script **findDup.sh** with following code:

```
for n in $(seq 1 13)
do
        no_of_lines=$(grep -n color$n= test.php|wc -l)
        if  [ $no_of_lines -gt 1 ]
        then
                grep -n color$n= test.php
                echo "--------"
        fi
done
```

When you run it in directory containing your **test.php** you will get duplicate lines with line numbers.

Example:

```
$ ./findDup.sh
3:$color3=$_POST['color3'] ?? '';
6:$color3=$_POST['color3'] ?? '';
--------
9:$color13=$_POST['color13'] ?? '';
13:$color13=$_POST['color13'] ?? '';
--------
```

You may change limit from 13 to anything you want in above script.